# Cosa significa "accantonamenti di legge"?

Tags: word-meaning, translation, meaning

Mi piacerebbe fare una domanda su un'espressione che ho trovato negli statuti di una società.

In un articolo si parla del "bilancio ed utili" e, dopo, si dice:

> Gli utili netti risultanti dal bilancio, dedotto degli eventuali **accantonamenti di legge**, verranno ripartiti tra gli azionisti salvo che l'Assamblea deliberi degli **speciali accantonamenti** oppure disponga il rinvio degli stessi, in tutto o in parte, agli esercizi successivi.

Mi potresti spiegare cos'è questo "accantonamento di legge" e questo "speciale accantonamento"?

Grazie!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'***accantonamento di legge*** detto anche ***accantonamento di utili a riserva legale*** è una fattispecie stabilita dall' Art. 2430 Codice civile:

> “Dagli utili netti annuali deve essere dedotta una somma
>   corrispondente almeno alla ventesima parte di essi per costituire una
>   riserva, fino a che questa non abbia raggiunto il quinto del capitale
>   sociale. La riserva deve essere reintegrata a norma del comma
>   precedente se viene diminuita per qualsiasi ragione. Sono salve le
>   disposizioni delle leggi speciali”.

Quindi nelle società di capitali è obbligatorio costituire un fondo di riserva destinando parte degli utili annuali. L'intento del legislatore è quello di conferire alle società una maggiore solidità e patrimonializzazione.
[Qui](http://www.marchegianionline.net/appro/appro_634.htm) trovi degli esempi specifici.

L'***accantonamento speciale*** è un'ulteriore quota degli utili che invece di venire distribuita tra i soci e azionisti viene destinata a particolari esigenze contingenti, ad esempio una causa legale che, se vedesse l'azienda soccombente in giudizio, potrebbe portare ad un risarcimento danni verso terzi.

Puoi trovare un esempio di accantonamento speciale in [questo testo di contabilità](https://books.google.it/books?id=f3WuO33Bo2cC&pg=PA536&lpg=PA536&dq=accantonamenti%20speciali&source=bl&ots=DQ3tGzl773&sig=6QK3ZhRiLN3kuOZ1fKU7fiHDGM8&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw66WW5vbSAhUJcBoKHfm9DIEQ6AEILzAD#v=onepage&q=accantonamenti%20speciali&f=false).

Answer (score 6):

Una domanda molto tecnica. In parole semplici si tratta di somme di danaro che, per diversi motivi, vengono "accantonate" ossia messe da parte in appositi fondi per un eventuale   utilizzo futuro.
Gli accantonamenti posso essere stabiliti dalla legge, ad esempio dal codice civile, oppure essere  fatti per prudenza dagli amministratori di una società.

Vedi:

[Gli accantonamenti rischi ed oneri nel bilancio d’esercizio](https://www.commercialistatelematico.com/articoli/2012/04/gli-accontonamenti-rischi-ed-oneri-nel-bilancio-desercizio.html):

> L’ art. 2424-bis del codice civile detta le regole a cui gli amministratori si devono ispirare per l’eventuale stanziamento di accantonamenti per fondi “rischi e oneri”:
>
> – ***competenza economica***: devono riferirsi a fatti inerenti all’esercizio;
>
> – ***prudenza***: devono stanziare tali accantonamenti al fine di rappresentare in modo chiaro,veritiero e corretto la situazione aziendale.